# How to get the number of subscribers on a topic?

Tags: ros, ros-hydro, topic, rostopic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everybody!

I want to know the list (or number) of subscribers on a topic programmatically. I know that I can use the **rostopic list** but I need that information in my node.

Thanks!

**Edit:** There is a method to find it: `uint32_t ros::Publisher::getNumSubscribers()` const
But I need to know the number of subscribers on a topic from another node and I don't have the Publisher object, just the name of the topic

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/173295/how-to-get-the-number-of-subscribers-on-a-topic?/) by [ricardoej](https://answers.ros.org/users/13141/ricardoej/) on ROS Answers with karma: 85 on 2014-06-10

Post score: 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[uint32_t ros::Publisher::getNumSubscribers() const](http://docs.ros.org/hydro/api/roscpp/html/classros_1_1Publisher.html#ad56c8e954020290dcb87cd6bbd330a2b)

> Returns the number of subscribers that are currently connected to this Publisher.

---

Originally posted by [ipso](https://answers.ros.org/users/2486/ipso/) with karma: 1416 on 2014-06-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ricardoej](https://answers.ros.org/users/13141/ricardoej/) on 2014-06-11**:
Thanks for the reply, but I'll put more information about my problem: when I have the Publisher object I know that I can use this method. But I need to know the number of subscribers in another node. I don't have the Publisher object, just the name of the topic.

**Comment by [Cerin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2186/cerin/) on 2018-04-28**:
"AttributeError: 'Publisher' object has no attribute 'getNumSubcribers'"

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-04-29**:
@Cerin: this is C++, not Python.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-04-29**:
With `rospy`, use [get_num_connections()](https://docs.ros.org/en/melodic/api/rospy/html/rospy.topics.Topic-class.html#get_num_connections).

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Never used it myself, but perhaps the [TopicManager](http://docs.ros.org/api/roscpp/html/classros_1_1TopicManager.html) would help?

---

Originally posted by [kramer](https://answers.ros.org/users/2050/kramer/) with karma: 1470 on 2014-06-12

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2